# Xcode 6.0 taking forever to archive my project

Tags: ios8, archive, xcode6

Xcode 6.0 taking about 8 hours to archive a fairly large project! Any idea how to make the archiving project faster? The archiving just gets stuck for hours at compiling 42 of 42 source files. Also, sometimes Xcode just crashing after hours of attempting to archive.

I recently upgraded my Mac to a 2.3GHz quad-core Intel Core i7 processor and 16GB RAM, but unfortunately that didn't help. I want to understand if it is a PC configuration issue or an Xcode issue. In other words, if I upgrade to a Mac Pro, would that help?

Answer (score 0):

Try to cancel archive, restart and try again.
If this doesn't work use other old method.

1. Build you project. Go to left pane-> product ->here you will see .app.
2. Show in finder .app file under product folder, drag and app in .app in iTunes.
3. There you will see you app in iTunes, again show in finder and you will see ipa file.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Once I have the .ipa file how do I submit it to the App Store? Also, the .ipa file in iTunes has no icon.

Comment: you need to study this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, but there's nothing here about uploading a .ipa file directly.

Comment: You need to use application loader for the same.

Comment: That didn't work because of provisioning profile related error. The provisioning profile is the one I always use to upload this app. Do you think the slow archiving has to do with the speed of my PC? My other apps that are smaller with less assets, archive very fast (a couple of minutes).