# Xcode: Problems with getting my App to the AppStore

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I am trying to upload my app to the AppStore with Application Loader

I tried to archive my project in order to generate the "ipa" file for Application Loader and the archive process got stuck at "Compiling swift sources" for almost 5hrs; I took to the response I read from - [Xcode 6.0 taking forever to archive my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25780831/xcode-6-0-taking-forever-to-archive-my-project) and I successfully generated the **.ipa** file with iTunes but while trying to upload with Application Loader, I get the error:

```
ERROR ITMS-90161: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning
profile included in the bundle com.youngbobby.MyAppName
[Payload/MyAppName.app] is invalid. [Missing code-signing 
certificate]. A Distribution Provisioning profile should be used when 
submitting apps to the App Store. For more information, visit the iOS 
Developer Portal."
```

I have generated my keychain certificate and my distribution provisioning profile and I still get that error during submission. Do you think the error is related to the method I used? Do I have to maintain the traditional "archive" method? If yes, what would be the fastest way to archive and generate my **.ipa** file? I have tried enabling **Whole Module Optimisation** as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30615262/xcode-6-3-not-archive-and-get-stucks-when-compiling-swift-source-files) all to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## EDIT

I did a quick check on **why my archive process was stuck at "Compiling swift sources"** using "**cmd + 8**" and I noticed that my local Data store swift file which is a **long Dictionary** of type [[String:Anyobject]] was the cause of the problem. I can't really explain why it is so but I want to maintain the traditional method of archive and send because it seems using iTunes to generate my ipa file does not agree with my provisioning profile.

Comment: You might need to manually remove your old provisional profile from your Xcode:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732251/how-to-remove-provisioning-profiles-from-xcode-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got my problem solved.

It seems all I needed to do while my app was compiling swift sources was to **WAIT**

I reduced the amount of Data in my Datastore file and the Archive process took less than 10 seconds to archive.

Pity, Xcode does not show a Timer to calculate how long it would take to archive a project and looking at the progress bar does not really guarantee that the process is working as in my case was a relatively huge one. So, maintaining the huge data I had, I simply had a 6hr nap and by the time I was up, my project was successfully archived and all other processes worked seamlessly :)

If you find your project **'stuck at compiling swift sources'** during Archive Process, all you need to do is **Wait.**

Comment: You stated two problems in your question.  I answered the one related to the error you were seeing.  You then changed to go back to trying to address the original problem of long compile times.  It makes it very difficult for people to benefit from these questions and answers if you keep your questions clear, specific, and with a single issue.  Changing the question in the middle is not recommended.  Usually, I would recommend that you create a new question to address the long compile time.  Also, it would be helpful for others to know how much data you had in your Datastore.

Comment: @wottle I appreciate your kind efforts in helping me solve my problem hence my upvote to your answer but my answer was what helped me solve my problem which i explained clearly. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not too concerned with the upvote.  I'm more concerned with the fact that your question title specifies problems getting to the app store, and the most prominent part of the question is the error around provisioning profiles, but your accepted answer is around long compile times.  In the long run, it will be hard for people to come to this question and figure out what the true question is and why the answer is what it is.  Thanks for considering my comments.

Answer (score 1):

When you are building the project, it is still building for debugging, hence it is using the development provisioning profile.

Before you do the build to create the .app, go to the Scheme (just to the right of the stop button, to the left of the device on which you are running).

[image: edit scheme option]

Click that and choose "Edit Scheme..."

Under the Run section, there is a setting for Build Configuration.

[image: Build configuration screen]

Change that from Debug to Release (if you are using the standard build config and you have configured the Release config to use your distribution profile and signing identity).

Close that window, then change your device to the generic "iOS Device option (make sure you don't have any devices plugged into your Mac).

[image: Device selection options]

Once you've done that, run your build again and the ipa created should be built with your release configuration and signed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a Development Provisioning profile.
Go to your dev center.
Create a new provisioning profile, select App Store and select your bundle ID. create that and download it.
Control drag that provisioning profile to Xcode, Change build settings in target and project to the one you downloaded now and as `Distribution`.
Compile and build your app. Archive it and start uploading it to App store.
That should do it.
P.S do select your team correctly before you configure your build settings.

## EDIT

If you already have done these steps just revoke the old one and create a new Provisioning profile and check.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It was a Distribution Provisioning Profile I created like I mentioned in my post. The only different thing form what you posted was that I double clicked the provisioning profile and I like to believe that it adds it automatically. Meanwhile I just changed build settings like you suggested from 'Automatic' to my Provision profile name and I got error `No codesigning identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) that match the provisioning profile specified in your build settings (“prov file”) were found.`

Comment: You got to set your Team as your developer account in your General of your project settings.

Comment: I get stuck while compiling my DataStore.swift file using the archive method. I don't think the provisioning profile works with the iTunes method i used.

Comment: Is it giving the same error as the method i mentioned?

Comment: Are you using Obj C and swift code together in some file or some class embedded in your project?

Comment: no, the file giving me problems when compiling is my Datastore swift file which is a dictionary of data in the form [[String:AnyObject]]

Comment: let me ask that question again, does your application has .h and .m file along with .swift file?